# Sinatra and Slim return Ruby function

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I have a small web application built using Sinatra and uses Slim templates.
In my `functions.rb` file, I defined a hash called `$locations` and I want to use a function to return values from within the hash. Here is what I have:

```
# functions.rb
$locations = Hash[
  'wa' => Hash[
    'capital' => 'Olympia'
  ],
  'or' => Hash[
    'capital' => 'Salem'
  ]
]
def foobar
  $locations.each do |key, value|
    $locations[key]['capital']
  end
end
```

My Slim file

```
/ layout.slim
div#capitals = foobar
```

When rendered, the page has a div with an ID of capitals, but the content is just the entire hash printed out with brackets. If I change the inside of the `each do` to this: `puts $locations[key]['capital']` and run the function in the command line, it works perfectly. How can I get this to work in Sinatra?

Basically, I want to accomplish this PHP script with Ruby instead (be able to call the function anywhere in my script and have it print out the `<div>` tags):

```
<?php
$locations = array(
  'wa' => array(
    'capital' => 'Olympia'
  ),
  'or' => array(
    'capital' => 'Salem'
  )
);

function foobar($array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div>" . $array[$key]['capital'] . "</div>";
  }
}
foobar($locations);
```

Comment: `$` as a variable prefix in Ruby means *global variable* and these are best avoided. Try declaring this as a constant like `LOCATIONS`.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for this comment, it has led me to research more about variables in Ruby and I have been able to improve my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, `value` *is* the hash at that key. Additionally, you want to return the capitals to the caller. `#each` enumerates over the elements but returns the collection, not the values returned by the block at each iteration. You want `#map` (or `#collect`):

```
def foobar
  $locations.map do |_key, value|
    value['capital']
  end
end
```

Or:

```
def foobar
  $locations.values.map do |value|
    value['capital']
  end
end
```

UPDATE: I don't know a lot of Slim, but based on your PHP example it seems to me you want something like:

```
- for capital in foobar
  div= capital
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have a better understanding of what is going on. However, it seems different than I expected. Ultimately, I want to store the capitals in the Hash and then use the function to print out an HTML `<select>` with `<option>` tags on the inside with each capital; I want to be able to call the function to print out the select wherever I want in my application.

Comment: @水口玄造 Does that help?